# How can I play a sound with defined start- and end-time in .Net

Tags: c#, media-player, audio, duration

In my C# project I want to play a sound with a specified start- and end time.

I used the `System.Media.SoundPlayer` with the `.Play()` function. But with this function I can only play the whole sound file or can abort it after I have counted the runtime.

In fact I want to say, that the given sound file should start for example at time 1m:25s:30ms and should end at time 1m:50s:00ms or after a duration of 10s or so.

Does anybody know a simple solution for his problem?

Thanks 4 help.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531789/how-to-play-a-music-file-for-a-specified-amount-of-time

Comment: ok this is what I have written above, that I could do that. But how can I say that the sound should not start at the start but for example several seconds after the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the End I use the NAudio library. That can handle this - not in a perfect way but ok.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372540/2936206

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but this question got me wondering if you can do something like this:

```
long startPositionInBytes = 512;
long endPositionInBytes = 2048;

using ( var audioStream = File.OpenRead(@"audio.wav") )
{
    audioStream.Position = startPositionInBytes;

    using ( var player = new SoundPlayer(audioStream) )
    {
        player.Play();

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        } while ( audioStream.Position <= endPositionInBytes );

        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: could work. But do u have an idea how I can estimat the byte position for the times? They are affected by sample rate and compression a.s.o. .

Comment: Not without writing code that can interpret the wave format, at which point you might as well go ahead and implement the audio playback yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to play a Background Media Player (for e.g., an audio file) which would start from a specific time and would work for a certain duration, then this code snippet could also be useful:

```
StorageFile mediaFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);//the path
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetFileSource(mediaFile);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000/*enter the start time here*/);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000/*for how long you want to play*/));
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown();//stops the player
```

**But this would only work for Windows 8.1 and above.
For more information, click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn652527)...

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using Windows Media Player in a C sharp program with a timer control and an open dialog.
I followed a sample that used buttons on the form and made the media player invisible.
After opening the file with an Open button that used the open dialog to open the mp3 file, on the Play button I put this code [the end effect is that it started the file in position 28.00 and ended it in position 32.50]:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    timer1.Start();
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 28.00;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();    
}
```

Then in the timer tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition >= 32.50)
    { axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause(); }
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition);     
}
```